# mostrar correctamente una impresion con JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json

### El único error que sale es que quiero que se muestre el array y la suma en el JSON.stringify(); pero solo me muestra la primera variable y en esa misma se ponen los dos parámetros

ósea array [(como debería ser) numero, numero, numero] y toma esa misma variable array[(y acá muestra la suma de ese array]
y viceversa
si pongo los parámetros al revés es lo mismo solo que ahora ya toma la otra variable ejemplo :
suma [[(y acá muestra la suma de ese array] y toma esa misma variable suma [numero, numero, numero]
lo que quiero es verificar que se estén recibiendo correctamente para después mandarlo a mi archivo de php el cual es el código comentado que esta a lo ultimo ##

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> $ </p> <input type="text" class="inputcolor " name="" id="inputventa">
                        <button type="submit" id="añadir" class="btn btn-color ">Añadir</button>
                        
                         <ul id="lista"> </ul>
                         
                         <p>
                            Total $---
                        <ul id="listaT"> </ul>
                        </p>
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        <script>
    $("#añadir").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // llamar a mis funciones para anadir datos de JS
        listado();
    });
    </script>

    <script>
     $("#guardar").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // llamar a mis funciones para anadir datos de JS
        enviar();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hola. **ósea** es un adjetivo que relaciona con los huesos. Si quieres decir algo como **es decir ...**, **aclaro ...**, etc., debes separar: **o sea** dónde **o** presenta una alternativa y **sea** es un inflexión verbal (imperativo del verbo ser).

Comment: lo corrigió el navegador

Comment: te lo corrigió porque lo pusiste ligado y son dos palabras

Comment: si esta bien...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estas pasando 1 solo paramentro a una funcion que recibe 2 argumentos

y aparte le estas enviado 2 tipos de datos primero envias un `array` y luego un `int`

solo deja un argumento de tipo `array` y trabaja con eso ejemplo:

```js
const agregarVar = document.querySelector('#añadir');
const inputAgregarVar = document.querySelector('#inputventa');


var arrayinput = [];

function listado() {
    if ((inputAgregarVar.value == '')) {
        alert('vacio');
        inputventa.focus();
    } else
    if (inputAgregarVar.value >= 0) {
        arrayinput.push(parseFloat(inputAgregarVar.value));
        inputAgregarVar.value = '';
        inputAgregarVar.focus();
        mostrar(arrayinput);
        sumar(arrayinput);
        // envias un arreglo
        enviar(arrayinput);
    } else
        alert('Debe de ser positivo');
    inputventa.focus();
};

function mostrar(arrayinput) {
    var listaUlVar = document.querySelector('#lista');
    listaUlVar.innerHTML = '';
    for (i of arrayinput) {
        var listaLi = document.createElement('li');
        listaUlVar.appendChild(listaLi);
        listaLi.innerText = i;
        console.log(i);
    }
}

function sumar(arrayinput) {
    var listaT = document.querySelector('#listaT');
    listaT.innerHTML = '';
    let suma = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayinput.length; i++) {
        suma += arrayinput[i];
    }
    var listaLi = document.createElement('li');
    listaT.appendChild(listaLi);
    listaLi.innerText = suma;
    console.log("suma total", suma);
    // envias un int
    //enviar(suma);
}

// vamos a recibir un solo dato
function enviar(arrayinput) {

    let datosAEnviar = {
        // sumamos todo el arreglo
        suma: arrayinput.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0),
        array: arrayinput

    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(datosAEnviar));
    /*
    let configOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Conten-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(datosAEnviar)
    }
    fetch("http://localhost/Proyectos/panaderia/administrador/admin/procesos/Procesoventa.php", configOptions)
        .then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> $ </p> <input type="text" class="inputcolor " name="" id="inputventa">
                        <button type="submit" id="añadir" class="btn btn-color ">Añadir</button>
                        
                         <ul id="lista"> </ul>
                         
                         <p>
                            Total $---
                        <ul id="listaT"> </ul>
                        </p>
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        <script>
    $("#añadir").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // llamar a mis funciones para anadir datos de JS
        listado();
    });
    </script>

    <script>
     $("#guardar").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // llamar a mis funciones para anadir datos de JS
        enviar();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: gracias, tendré problemas cuando lo quiera mandarlo a un archivo de php para guardarlo ala base de datos?